# How do I uninstall JVCL?

Tags: delphi, jvcl

I want to uninstall Jedi because it replaces my GIF handling library. Even though I uninstalled JVCL, Delphi keeps using the Jedi gif library and it keeps adding the JVGif unit to my project which adds extra compiling time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to nicely uninstall Jedi.

To uninstall Jedi and restore the functionality of previous GIF library do this:

1. Close Delphi
2. Run the JCL uninstaller
3. Run the JVCL uninstaller
4. Run the cleaning utility as explained by Mason Wheeler (in both folders)
5. Manually delete JCL folders
6. Manually delete JVCL folders
7. Start Delphi. Reinstall TGifImage component

Note: To start the uninstallers run the "install.bat".

Comment: @Mason's method seems rather automatic.

Comment: The JVCL should be uninstalled before the JCL. The clean.bat isn't necessary if you delete the folders.

Comment: @AndreasHausladen - It is but it seems it failed in my case. There are the steps for manual uninstall.

Answer (score 4):

Run the JVCL installer and uninstall.  Then open the JVCL root folder in the command line and type "clean.bat all" and that should take care of the rest of it.

Comment: I ran the uninstaller. I supposed it will actually uninstall the Jedi. It will be nice if the uninstaller will call automatically clean.bat and other cleaning utilities to actually uninstall the Jedi.